# Reading selected parts of a file of unknown name

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am having a lot of datafiles with unknown names. I have figured out a way to get them all read and printed but I want to make graphs of them so I need the data in a way that is workable.

The datafiles are very neatly arranged (every line of the header contains information on what is stored there) but I am having trouble making a script that selects the data I need. The first 50+ lines of the file contain headers of which I need only a few to be used, this poses no problem when using something like:

```
    for filename in glob.glob(fullpath):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if 'xx' in line:
                     Do my thing
                if 'yy' in line:
                     Do my thing etc.
```

But below the headers there is a block of data of undetermined number of columns and undetermined number of lines (number of columns and what each column is, is specified in the headers). This I can't get read in a way that a graph can be made by for example matplotlib. (I can get it right by manually copying the data to a separate file and read that to a plottable format but that is not what I want to do every time of every file...) The line before the data starts contains the very useful #eoh but I can't figure out a way to combine the selective reading of the first 50+ lines and then swith to reading everything into an array. If there are methods to do what I want in a better way (including the selection of the map and seeing which files are there and readable) I am open to suggestions.

**Update:**
The solution proposed by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest seems very useful but I don't get it to work. 
So I'll start with the data mentioned as missing in the answer.
Columnnames are given in the following format:

#COLUMNINFO= NUMBER1, UNIT, MEASUREMENT, NUMBER2

In this format number1 is the columnnumber, unit is the unit of the measurement, measurement is what is measured and number2 is in numbers what is measured. 
The data is separated by spaces but that won't be a problem, I suspect.

I tried to implement the reading of the headers in the loop to determine the end of the headers, which failed to have any visible effects, even the print commands to check intermediate results did not show. 
Once I put 'print line' after 'for line in f:' I thought I could see what went wrong but it appears as if the whole loop is ignored, including the break command which causes an error since the file is done reading and no data is left to read for the other parts...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you looked into `pandas`? Can be of great assistance when it comes to arranging data in columns and is very *matplotlib-friendly*..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the header has a certain character at the beginning of each line, this can be used to filter the header out automatically. Using `numpy` you could use `numpy.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=";", comment="#")` to load the data and every line starting with `#` would simply be ignored. 
I don't know if this is the case here?!

In the case that you describe, where you have a header-ending flag `#eoh` you could first read in the header line by line to find out how many lines you later need to ignore and then use that number when loading the file.

I have assembled a little example, how it could work.

```
def readFile(filename):
    #first find the number of lines to skip in the header
    eoh = 0
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            eoh = eoh+1
            if "#eoh" in line:
                break
    # now at this point we need to find out about the column names
    # but as no data is given as example, this is impossible
    columnnames = []            
    # load the file by skipping eoh lines,
    # the rest should be well behaving
    a = np.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header = eoh, delimiter=";" )

    return a, columnnames

def plot(a, columnnames, show=True, save=False, filename="something"):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    # plot the forth column agains the second
    ax.plot(a[:, 1], a[:,3])    
    # if we had some columnname, we could also plot
    # column named "ulf" against the one named "alf"
    #ax.plot(a[:, columnnames.index("alf")], a[:,columnnames.index("ulf")]) 

    #now save and/or show
    if save:
        plt.savefig(filename+".png")
    if show:
        plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    fullpath = "path/to/files/file*.txt" # or whatever       
    for filename in glob.glob(fullpath):
        a, columnnames = readFile(filename)
        plot(a, columnnames, show=True, save=False, filename=filename[:-4])
```

One remaining problem is the names of the columns. Since you did not provide any example data, it's hard to estimate how to exactly do that.

This all assumes that you do not have any missing data in between or anything of that kind. If this was the case, then you'd need to use all the arguments to [`numpy.genfromtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) to filter the data accordingly.

Comment: Looks great, since this is a side-project for me I don't have time to implement it right now but it looks very promising. I especially like the 'def' part since I wasn't aware it or something similar existed in python.